# How to add NDK to project in AS 2.1

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So, there is a lot of info about NDK but it seems to all be about AS < 2.

What is the exact process to add C++ support to a standard AS java project? Is the process the same or has much of it been automated?

I'd like the most automated way to accomplish this using the latest tools. I don't want to have to pre-build the C++ files or deal with any hassle. It should just work the way it is suppose to or, at this point, I'd rather wait.

Any ideas?